# R package install from Github, Error and Warning

Tags: r, github, package

I am trying to install the version of `mvabund` from `github (3.11.8)` as the version on `cran (3.11.7)` has an issue with the summary function. I have followed the instructions to use `devtools`:

```
install.packages("devtools", dep=TRUE)

library(devtools)

install_github("mvabund", username="aliceyiwang")
```

It installs `Rtools` to build the package and then is produces the following error message and warning message:

> Error: Could not find build tools necessary to build mvabund In addition: Warning message: Username parameter is deprecated. Please use aliceyiwang/mvabund

I tried installing `Rtools` before running the `install_github` code but it still reinstalls `Rtools`. I am not sure what to do from here

I am using `Windows 10` and I have `R v 3.2.5`

Comment: Try using install_github("aliceyiwang/mvabund") and Rtools should be in your environment variable path

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the Rtools page:

> We have found that the build process for R is quite sensitive to the choice of tools: please follow our instructions exactly, even to the choice of particular versions of the tools.

If it re-installs Rtools, the version may not be the one you need for your R version. Is your version up-to-date?

One other option is to try to dowload the package from the github page and install it from a local directory with `install`

Comment: I have rtools33, and R version 3.2.5 so I think they should be compatible, both are 64bit as well. I have also tried what chinsoon12 suggested but that also tries to install rtools. What appears to be happening is; Rstudio tries to download rtools, after downloading, but before it has installed, the command error "Could not find build tools necessary to build mvabund In addition" is displayed and then rtools installs. at which point I try to Install the package again and rtools begins downloading again. is there a way for me to point Rstudio to the already installed rtools?